# Unable to install ros_control on ubuntu 18.04 melodic

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried both . .

sudo apt install ros-melodic-ros-control* ros-melodic-control*

sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-ros-control ros-melodic-ros-controllers

Getting the following errors and warnings

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.18.0-21 linux-headers-4.18.0-21-generic
  linux-image-4.18.0-21-generic linux-modules-4.18.0-21-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-21-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ros-melodic-ackermann-steering-controller ros-melodic-combined-robot-hw
  ros-melodic-combined-robot-hw-tests ros-melodic-controller-manager-tests
  ros-melodic-effort-controllers ros-melodic-force-torque-sensor-controller
  ros-melodic-gripper-action-controller ros-melodic-imu-sensor-controller
  ros-melodic-joint-trajectory-controller
  ros-melodic-rqt-joint-trajectory-controller ros-melodic-velocity-controllers
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ros-melodic-ackermann-steering-controller ros-melodic-combined-robot-hw
  ros-melodic-combined-robot-hw-tests ros-melodic-controller-manager-tests
  ros-melodic-effort-controllers ros-melodic-force-torque-sensor-controller
  ros-melodic-gripper-action-controller ros-melodic-imu-sensor-controller
  ros-melodic-joint-trajectory-controller ros-melodic-ros-control
  ros-melodic-ros-controllers ros-melodic-rqt-joint-trajectory-controller
  ros-melodic-velocity-controllers
0 upgraded, 13 newly installed, 0 to remove and 25 not upgraded.
Need to get 909 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,150 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 ros-melodic-ackermann-steering-controller amd64 0.15.0-0bionic.20190329.165914
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Err:2 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 ros-melodic-combined-robot-hw amd64 0.15.1-0bionic.20190320.160509
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Err:3 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 ros-melodic-controller-manager-tests amd64 0.15.1-0bionic.20190320.162601
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Err:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 ros-melodic-combined-robot-hw-tests amd64 0.15.1-0bionic.20190320.163221
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Err:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 ros-melodic-effort-controllers amd64 0.15.0-0bionic.20190329.170136
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Err:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 ros-melodic-force-torque-sensor-controller amd64 0.15.0-0bionic.20190329.165504
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Err:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 ros-melodic-gripper-action-controller amd64 0.15.0-0bionic.20190329.170410
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Err:8 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 ros-melodic-imu-sensor-controller amd64 0.15.0-0bionic.20190329.170643
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Err:9 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 ros-melodic-joint-trajectory-controller amd64 0.15.0-0bionic.20190329.171202
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Err:10 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 ros-melodic-ros-control amd64 0.15.1-0bionic.20190320.163958
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Err:11 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 ros-melodic-rqt-joint-trajectory-controller amd64 0.15.0-0bionic.20190329.170951
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Err:12 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 ros-melodic-velocity-controllers amd64 0.15.0-0bionic.20190329.171037
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Err:13 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 ros-melodic-ros-controllers amd64 0.15.0-0bionic.20190329.172058
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-melodic-ackermann-steering-controller/ros-melodic-ackermann-steering-controller_0.15.0-0bionic.20190329.165914_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-melodic-combined-robot-hw/ros-melodic-combined-robot-hw_0.15.1-0bionic.20190320.160509_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-melodic-controller-manager-tests/ros-melodic-controller-manager-tests_0.15.1-0bionic.20190320.162601_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-melodic-combined-robot-hw-tests/ros-melodic-combined-robot-hw-tests_0.15.1-0bionic.20190320.163221_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-melodic-effort-controllers/ros-melodic-effort-controllers_0.15.0-0bionic.20190329.170136_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-melodic-force-torque-sensor-controller/ros-melodic-force-torque-sensor-controller_0.15.0-0bionic.20190329.165504_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-melodic-gripper-action-controller/ros-melodic-gripper-action-controller_0.15.0-0bionic.20190329.170410_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-melodic-imu-sensor-controller/ros-melodic-imu-sensor-controller_0.15.0-0bionic.20190329.170643_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-melodic-joint-trajectory-controller/ros-melodic-joint-trajectory-controller_0.15.0-0bionic.20190329.171202_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-melodic-ros-control/ros-melodic-ros-control_0.15.1-0bionic.20190320.163958_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-melodic-rqt-joint-trajectory-controller/ros-melodic-rqt-joint-trajectory-controller_0.15.0-0bionic.20190329.170951_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-melodic-velocity-controllers/ros-melodic-velocity-controllers_0.15.0-0bionic.20190329.171037_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-melodic-ros-controllers/ros-melodic-ros-controllers_0.15.0-0bionic.20190329.172058_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326993/unable-to-install-ros_control-on-ubuntu-18.04-melodic-./) by [Ish Rajesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/43524/ish-rajesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> 20190329
> ```

I believe this is another instance of #q325039.

Please follow those instructions and try again.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
Do this command and then sudo apt update

then try to install that package of ros-control

---

Originally posted by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) with karma: 139 on 2019-06-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-26**:
Yes, that is exactly what is documented in #q325039, that was linked from the comment.

**Comment by [Ish Rajesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/43524/ish-rajesh/) on 2019-06-26**:
Thanks , It worked well